# Interlocked Singly Linked Lists (SList) with MinGW

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

When I try to port my Win32 code from Microsoft toolchain to MinGW, most code compiles fine, but there are few exceptions. One particular API which seems to be missing in MinGW is [SList API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (including InitializeSListHead, InterlockedPushEntrySList) - when I compile my sources, I get error about those functions being not defined. What can I do to have this 
API available under MinGW? Is there some Win32 SDK I could update, or something like that?

Comment: I recommend [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), it has a much more complete library than mingw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current MinGW (based on GCC 4.6.2) already contains SList API, but you need to indicate you are compiling for the Windows target supporting it by [defining a preprocessor value _WIN32_WINNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt)=0x0501 or higher (which indicates Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows XP with SP2).

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://equation.com and download their perfect MinGW build with the latest gcc 4.8+

From winbase.h (in equation's MinGW/include):

```
#if defined(_SLIST_HEADER_) && !defined(_NTOSP_)
  WINBASEAPI VOID WINAPI InitializeSListHead(PSLIST_HEADER ListHead);
  WINBASEAPI PSLIST_ENTRY WINAPI InterlockedPopEntrySList(PSLIST_HEADER ListHead);
  WINBASEAPI PSLIST_ENTRY WINAPI InterlockedPushEntrySList(PSLIST_HEADER ListHead,PSLIST_ENTRY ListEntry);
  WINBASEAPI PSLIST_ENTRY WINAPI InterlockedFlushSList(PSLIST_HEADER ListHead);
  WINBASEAPI USHORT WINAPI QueryDepthSList(PSLIST_HEADER ListHead);
#endif /* _SLIST_HEADER_ && !_NTOSP_ */
```

Comment: Please don't recommend a GCC development version.

Comment: I have checked the last stable version by them (4.7 based) and it already contains the SList API as well (I did not try if _WIN32_WINNT is required for this MinGW distribution).

Answer (score 0):

`QueryDepthSList();`  is missing from 4.7.1 headers. The other functions are there.